# How can I change the visual studio 2015 compiler to cygwin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, cygwin

Is it possible to change the visual studio 2015 compiler to Cygwin the ide is nice I would just like a different compiler.

Comment: Cygwin is not a compiler, it is a runtime environment. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I disagree with the "too broad" closure reason, and instead voted to close as "unclear". But being in the minority as the only person to choose that reason, the system misrepresented by vote as being for the majority. Oh well. Why do I think the question is unclear? The same reason as Robert: Cygwin is a runtime environment, not a compiler. You cannot change the Visual Studio 2015 compiler to Cygwin any more than you can change it to Unix. You can, however, change it to ICC, GCC, Clang, etc. You don't tell us which one you want to change it to. What does Cygwin have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use CMake to generate both Cygwin and Visual Studio projects. Write code in Visual Studio, build the Cygwin build via CMake. Only downside: updates to the Visual Studio `.vcxproj` file aren't sync'ed back to the CMakelist.txt file.